# Finding the mode in R, when there is more than one mode

Tags: r

I would like R to output all of the modes for a particular group. Currently, R is giving me just the single mode, which is fine if there is only one mode. However, I would like an output of all modes, if more than one exists. Below is the function I am using for the mode, and I was wondering how it could be modified so that I could do this?

```
Mode <- function(x) {
uni <- unique(x)
uni[which.max(tabulate(match(x, uni)))]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way in base R -

```
Mode <- function(x) {
 a <- table(x)
 as.numeric(names(a)[a == max(a)])
}

x <- c(1,2,2,3,3,4)

Mode(x)
[1] 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'modeest' package on CRAN. mvf() function stands for (most frequent value(s)) in the package returns mode(s) of given array.

```
mfv(x) # returns the most frequent value(s) for vector x.
```

For more information refer to documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/modeest/versions/2.1/topics/mfv).